# Error returning incompatible pointer incompatible C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make my function return a pointer to a struct, but the compiler keeps telling me that I'm returning an incompatible pointer type.

```
struct Array *createArray( unsigned int array_size )
{
    struct Array
    {
        unsigned int size;
        int *a;
    };
    struct Array *Array; //creates pointer to struct and then allocates appropriate memory
    Array = malloc( sizeof( struct Array ) );
    if ( array_size > 0 )
    {
        Array->size = array_size;
        Array->a = malloc( array_size * sizeof( unsigned int ) ); // size of array dependent on array_size
        for ( int *counter = ( *Array ).a; counter < ( ( *Array ).a + array_size ); counter++ )
        {
            Array->a = 0; // initializes all array elements to zero
        }
        return Array;
    }
    //else  
    //  return Array;
}
```

The error I get is:

> error: incompatible pointer types returning 'struct Array *'
>         from a function with result type 'struct Array *'
>                   return Array;

What I don't understand is why it says this. Isn't the value I'm returning the same as what was specified? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inner definition of `struct Array` hides outer declaration, and is therefore a different type. When posting code to StackOverflow, avoid tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the struct Array inside the function

Move the struct outside the function to make it work

the scope of the struct is in the function, not outside